# Git History both rewritten and unchanged?

Tags: git

So I let Git rewrite history in all my branches over night, and when I looked for the results, I saw this:
[image]

```
      E:\zeus>git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "rm -rf ZeusSRC_Hardware_RPi_image_Raspberry Pi_außen_20.05.2019.zip" --prune-empty -- --all
      Rewrite fa2be75c64ca78a296c8f78fc363beebecbf92a1 (1526/1526) (2745 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
      Ref 'refs/heads/Kunden' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/heads/Sensor' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/heads/Wetter' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/heads/ZEUS-5' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/heads/Zeus_Bug-13' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ADW' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Kunden' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Metzger' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Mond' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Sensor' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Sonne' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Wetter' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS-2' is unchanged
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS-3' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS-5' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS_BUG-12' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS_BUG-4' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS_BUG-6' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS_BUG-8' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ZEUS_BUG-9' was rewritten
      Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Zeus_Bug-13' was rewritten
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/metzger' is unchanged
      WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/tempAddFirstCode' is unchanged
      Ref 'refs/stash' was rewritten
```

So basically, git is showing me that it both did change and did not change stuff, somehow?

As I can see so far, the local parts were changed completely while the remotestuff has changed only partially. 
The size of the repository stayed the same (8 Gig) but it should have been reduced to 4Gig.

So two things:
First, has someone an idea what could be the reason for this mixed result?
Im running this on Win10, no admin privileges, from git CMD. 
Second, is such a result "problematic"? I mean, some stuff has changed and some hasnt. Should I remove and then clone the repository again, to have a clean basis for the next attempt?

Comment: Side note: the fact that `refs/stash` was rewritten probably means that your saved stash has been damaged. The stash code makes commits that don't behave the way most commits do, and filter-branch will sometimes remove one of them.

Answer (score 1):

1. If a ref is unchanged, the ref's history has never contained the removed files and directories since its first commit.
2. The size has not become smaller, because the related objects are still there in the repository. They will be there for a long time until they are garbage-collected some day. If they are wiped out immediately, it means you can't roll back the refs in case you regret or you run `git filter-branch` by mistake.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay
I read quite a few tutorials on rewriting history in order to reduce the size of a repository, and they all made it look like the size would be reduced immediately. It also sounded like the old commits would simply be modified, not removed (thats why its called rewriting, not deleting history).  It should be possible to roll back to these modified states, isnt it? I mean the point is to still have everything in place EXCEPT for the stuff I changed :D So am I just missing something? Is there a command to remove the old objects immediately?